# Why Include columns are not sorted in non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, b-tree, non-clustered-index

In the non-clustered index of SQL Server, to avoid bookmark lookups, we can use an `INCLUDE` clause to make the index cover more columns. The list of columns that will be part of include columns will be stored in the leaf level nodes of the B-tree structure of the non-clustered index.

Index key columns will be stored into the root and intermediate levels of nodes of the B-tree structure as well as in its leaf level nodes and while creating the index, we define its sorting type, either descending or ascending.

Then based on the index key columns sorting, why are the associated included columns not sorted? Or my imagination towards the structure and content of leaf-level nodes of the non-clustered index is wrong. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorted how? They're just included as additional columns - they're  **NOT** part of the (sorted) navigation tree structure of the index - they're just added to the leaf level data node.

Comment: so, in leaf level nodes, the index key columns are not stored along with the include columns? and if index key columns are there at leaf level and they are sorted then include columns will also be sorted? but if index keys will not be present into the leaf level node then include columns will just be there, in that case how the SQL server identify the row-wise association between index key columns and include columns?

Comment: The sorting happens in the **b-tree navigation structure**  of the index - and it includes all the **key columns**. Once you've reached the leaf level, it's just a data node - a page with data. The `INCLUDE` just adds a few more columns (their values) to that data page - this cannot be sorted in any way - it's just storing the additional columns for an entry.......

Comment: If you sort a list of people by lastname, firstname and include their city and state as additional columns - the b-tree navigaton structure of the index will make sure the entries are sorted by `(lastname, firstname)` - you you get `Abraham, John` before `Clinton, Bill` and before `Madison, Peter`. Then, for each of these entries, you add their city and state at the leaf level  `Abraham, John (Boston, MA)`, `Clinton, Bill (Little Rock, AK)`, `Madison, Peter (Chicago, IL)` - I don't understand how or what you want to be sorting here in the include columns....

Comment: I guess, for me the structure of leaf-level nodes is confusing. Can you please elaborate a little bit more, what data leaf node stores. I think if col1 in index key then this col1 will be there in leaf level. And if I do include(col2), then along with col1, col2 will also be there at leaf level. And if col1 is sorted there then the ordering of col2 will also be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I think i got it, the include columns will not be sorted but they will be associated with the index key columns and this association will be maintained in leaf-level nodes. The index key will be sorted, ascending or descending.

Comment: The leaf-level node stores: **(1)** all the index columns, **(2)** the clustering key column(s) (or a "row identifier", if there's no clustered index), and **(3)** any included columns